# How do I create array of dictionary in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, dictionary

I am so far new in iOS.
I tried a lot to get an output but didn't get.
Please help, I want to store data into an `Array` like this format in `Objective-C` language:

```
(
    {
    Appearance = Copper;
    Bitterness = 50;
    Style = "India Pale Ale (IPA)";
},
    {
    Appearance = "Jet Black";
    Bitterness = 35;
    Style = Stout;
},
    {
    Appearance = Copper;
    Bitterness = 25;
    Style = "English Brown Ale";
},
    {
    Appearance = "Deep Gold";
    Bitterness = 25;
    Style = Bock;
}
)
```

can anyone please help me out.

Comment: You should create a `Codable` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) object instead of dictionay to store your array

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @QuocNguyen The question is tagged Objective-C

Comment: @Larme, I didn't see it. In objective-c, you can create a `Class` instead of

Comment: thanku all for your valuable time

Comment: actually I'm having 3 array's for storing data- appearance, bitterness and style, now plz tell me next what  to do.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way to create `Array` of `Dictionary` :

Objective C :

```
NSArray *arrTemp = @[
                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Copper",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(50),
                       @"Style" : @"India Pale Ale (IPA)"},

                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Jet Black",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(35),
                       @"Style" : @"Stout"},

                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Copper",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(25),
                       @"Style" : @"English Brown Ale"},

                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Deep Gold",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(25),
                       @"Style" : @"Bock"}
                     ];
```

Swift :

```
        let arrTemp: [[String:Any]] = [
                                    ["Appearance" : "Copper",
                                     "Bitterness" : 50,
                                     "Style" : "India Pale Ale (IPA)"],

                                    ["Appearance" : "Jet Black",
                                    "Bitterness" : 35,
                                    "Style" : "Stout"],

                                    ["Appearance" : "Copper",
                                    "Bitterness" : 25,
                                    "Style" : "English Brown Ale"],

                                    ["Appearance" : "Deep Gold",
                                    "Bitterness" : 25,
                                    "Style" : "Bock"]
                                  ]
```

Comment: thnx for you reply @VRAwesome

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries are initialized like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ key : value, key2 : value2};
```

Arrays are initialized like this:

```
NSArray *array = @[Object1, Object2]
```

So you can create Dictionaries object as per your data and add to array like

```
NSArray *array = @[DicObject1, DicObject2]
```

Any doubt plz comment.

Comment: it helps a lot :) thnx @vivekDas